# Jackson json serializations fails for integer key

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do i convert the following JSON into a class in Jackson java

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "msg": "0 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully",
  "transaction_details": {
    "3690": {
      "mihpayid": "Not Found",
      "status": "Not Found"
    }
  }
}
```

The integer key in transaction_details causes an issue, we have no control over the format as its returned from a 3rd party payment gateway.

Comment: what is the issue? is it exception ?

Comment: provide your Jackson java please

Comment: please provide a mapping class

Comment: you can checkout here and see how your Java classes differ. it will generate Java Classes from JSON. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your following classes as per below,if not did then,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Jackson {

    private String status;
    private String msg;

    private TransactionDetails transaction_details = new TransactionDetails();

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public TransactionDetails getTransaction_details() {
        return transaction_details;
    }
    public void setTransaction_details(TransactionDetails transaction_details) {
        this.transaction_details = transaction_details;
    }

}

class TransactionDetails{

    private A3690 a3690;

    @JsonProperty("3690")
    public A3690 getA3690() {
        return a3690;
    }

    public void setA3690(A3690 a3690) {
        this.a3690 = a3690;
    }

}

class A3690{

    private String mihpayid ;
    private String status;

    public String getMihpayid() {
        return mihpayid;
    }
    public void setMihpayid(String mihpayid) {
        this.mihpayid = mihpayid;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

> you can use it likewise,  for creating Jackson Object to JSON,

```
String jsonString = null;

        try {

            Jackson jacksonObj = new Jackson(); // populate it as per needs...
            jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jacksonObj);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         System.out.println(jsonString); // will return JSON into String formate.
```

> And for converting String JSON to Jackson Object do likewise,

```
String str = "{"status":"status","msg":"msg","transaction_details":{"3690":{"mihpayid":"mihpayid","status":"status1"}}}"; 

        try {
            Jackson jacksonObject = objectMapper.readValue(str, Jackson.class);

            System.out.println(" Status -" + jacksonObject.getStatus() +  " : msg - " + jacksonObject.getMsg());

            System.out.println(" Mihpayid -" + jacksonObject.getTransaction_details().getA3690().getMihpayid() +  " : Status - " + jacksonObject.getTransaction_details().getA3690().getStatus());

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

**UPDATED :**

If **key 3690 is not fix** , 
i mean it's *randomly coming* then `need to refactoring`Jackson`class likewise`, ( here only Jackson class is enough for all , 
no need to create more classes as like above my mentioned )

public class Jackson {

```
private String status;
private String msg;

//private TransactionDetails transaction_details = new TransactionDetails();

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}
public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> transaction_details = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>(); 

@JsonProperty("transaction_details")
public HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> getMap() {
    return transaction_details;
}

public void setMap(HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> transaction_details) {
    this.transaction_details = transaction_details;
}
```

}

---

**Enjoy, Best of luck...!!!**

Comment: what if next key will be not `3690` but some another number?

Comment: key can be anything but need to fix it, i just put it '3690' because into question it's. what ever key you want just need to write @JsonProperty("key-value") here.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou you mean 3690 is randomly comming ?

Comment: I think it is not static, so `@JsonProperty()` is not an option. You need serialization to map here.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou see my UPDATED section , i did it, let me know still any thing what i missed then!!

Comment: I believe that deserialization to `Map<String, TransactionDetails>` will be better, because transaction details class looks statically typed. Besides, it is OP who finally decides, not me :)